# How can I create an ES6 class that creates new HTML elements using given tag name and has methods to manipulate it?

Tags: javascript, html, class, ecmascript-6, dom-manipulation

I am trying to create a class in ES6 that would create new HTML items with a given tag name. In it would be methods to append it or change innerHTML.

My questions: 
1) how to pass into the document.createElement a new tag name, because literal`${}` is not working as I would expect 
2) where to transform "this" - newly created "HTMLElement" into HTML element (createElement). I have a feeling it should not be in a constructor, but I don't know where to place it, do the class would transform it upon creating.

```
class HTMLElement {
  constructor (tagName){
    this.tagName = document.createElement(`${tagName}`);
  }

  addText(text) {
    this.innerHTML = text;
  }

  appendItem(parent) {
    let appendTo = document.getElementsByTagName(`${parent}`);
    appendTo.appendChild(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are probably thinking of it too generically, different type of events can have different parameters, so you should think about that and based on the tag names you should set the properties.
for example if you wanna create **button** it will have a **name**, which is not required for a **span** or **div** or if you wanna create a **input** element you may need to set some **default** **value**.

To handle this, you can either handle **tags** **individually** or **group** similar elements(**tags**) with common **properties**.

Answering your point,

1.) you can directly pass the value

```
this.tagName = document.createElement(tagName);
```

2.) "this" here is an object, and the element you have created is stored on this.tagName

```
appendItem(parent) {
    let appendTo = document.getElementsByTagName(parent);
    appendTo.appendChild(this.TagName);
  }
```

Comment: Hey Amit, sorry for a late reply! But to tell you the truth I only know what I really wanted to achieve right now, that I understand a little bit more about JS and patterns. What I actually wanted was a factory to create elements like this one we developed together with my course team [Element factory](https://github.com/Front-znad-zatoki/Star-Wars-Quiz/blob/main/src/app/utils/elementFactory.js). It creates html elements with given attributes. Sorry and thanks for the answer anyway!